# Interpreting The Derivative of a Function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

After re-reading some of my undergraduate ordinary differential equations textbooks, I wanted to receive some feedback regarding how I interpret the derivative of a function $f$ in terms of rates of change. Here is how I would describe (in an informal way) the derivative of a function:

> The derivative of a function $f$ measures the rate at which the value of the function changes with respect to a change in its argument.

Is this correct? The reason for my question is I have noticed it is common to hear people say "*the derivative of a function measures the rate of change **of the function** with respect to the variable $x$*" (of course, where $x$ is the argument of the function). This to me sounds a little informal in its own right, so I thought I might rewrite it a little. While my description is very closely related to [Wikipedia's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative), I wanted feedback nonetheless. If anyone has a better wording of this, please do share.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Yeah I like your wording better.

Comment: @copper.hat Good to hear. Do you have any suggestions for how to word this for evaluating the derivative at a specific point?

Comment: I think of it as the best linear (affine) model of $f$ (in some sense) at $x$, so evaluation is just evaluation of the linear model.

Comment: @copper.hat - That makes sense. Using my wording, would saying "the derivative of a function $f$ at the point $p$ measures the rate at which the value of the function changes with respect to a change in its argument at $p$" be okay as well?

Comment: @TaylorRendon It is correct, but it doesn't quite convey the linear (affine) part which is an important part.

Comment: @copper.hat - Gotcha! If I find myself describing it in terms of the best linear (affine) model of $f$ at $x$, then I will reference your description (-:.